# -Namespace option is not recognized in Scaffold-DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, scaffolding, ef-core-3.0

According to [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell#scaffold-dbcontext), `Scaffold-DbContext` should accpect a optional parameter `-Namespace`. However, seems that `Scaffold-DbContext` cannot recognize this parameter. Did I miss something?

---

Command Error:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=Stock;Trusted_Connection=True;User Id=sa;Password=P@ssw0rd;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Namespace Stock.Models.DTO

Scaffold-DbContext : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Namespace'.
At line:1 char:151
+ ... P@ssw0rd;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Namespace Stock.M ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Scaffold-DbContext], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Scaffold-DbContext
```

Packages installed:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: your EF Core version should be EFCore 5.0  onwards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-Namespace` works EF Core 5.0 onwards. your version is lower than that. Please upgrade EF Core

Answer (score 2):

Its enough to update package EntityFrameworkCode.Tools to v 5.0
At the time of writing ver 5.0 is prerelease, tick "Include prerelease" to make it appear in NuGet list (Visual Studio GUI).